# How do I output an array to a table in Excel VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a table named `foobar` that has `Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(11, 2))` (use `Range("foobar[#All]")` to include the header row). And there are other tables starting from row 13. So there is a blank line between (i.e., row 12). The table name is used by my collegues in several other macros. Now, I'd like to copy an array, say, `Redim array1(1 To n, 1 To 2)` to table `foobar`. As you see, n is a variable, and I have to make sure after I paste the array starting from `Cells(2, 1)`, it won't overwrite the tables below and there is still one blank line below table `foobar` to separate it from other tables. And the name foobar should also be kept.

---

How do I auto adjust/add/reduce the rows to match my array `array1` and not to destroy table `foobar` and other tables below it?

Comment: Do you also have other tables or data on the right of your table?

Comment: @A.S.H At this moment, not really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately you don't have data and tables on the same rows, so the task is easier. This code snippet changes the content of the table `foobar` while not affecting the table(s) below it.

```
Sub ChangeTableToArray(tbl As ListObject, ar)
  Dim newRows As Long: newRows = 1+ UBound(ar,1) - LBound(ar,1)
  If Not tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then tbl.DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
  If newRows > 1 Then tbl.HeaderRowRange.Resize(newRows - 1).Offset(2).EntireRow.Insert
  tbl.HeaderRowRange.Resize(newRows, 1+UBound(ar,2)-LBound(ar,2)).Offset(1).Value = ar
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Testing()
  Dim n As Long: n = 15
  ReDim ar(1 To n, 1 To 2)
  For n = 1 To n
    ar(n, 1) = n
    ar(n, 2) = n * n
  Next
  ChangeTableToArray Sheet2.ListObjects("foobar"), ar
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems your snippet breaks when there is only one row, i.e., set `n = 1` in `Sub Testing()`. However, it is very possible that `DataBodyRange` has only one record in practice.

Comment: @Nicholas yes because we cant resize the additional rows to insert with zero. All it needed is an additional check for this particular case. I added that and simplified the code a bit further.

Comment: What does condition `If .Rows.count > 1` do? Is it possible to replace `If .Rows.count > 1 Then .Delete` simply with `.Delete`?

Comment: @Nicholas In my tests it raised an error thinking I am attempting to empty table's data. This is weird bacuse if the `DataBodyRange` initially had more rows you can directly `.Delete` it, and it leaves one row in the table. But if it had initially one row, it raises an error. Did you try it on your side?

Comment: If it had initially one row, there are two scenarios. 1. Some cells in the row is populated. 2. All the cells in this row is empty. For scenario 1, it always works. For scenario 2, there are another two scenarios. 1. User enters the `delete` button on their computer for each cell (equivalent to clear the content I guess) 2. You can get empty row by deleting entire rows by right clicking and choosing `delete`. Only scenario 2 would trigger run-time error '91' at line `With tbl.DataBodyRange.EntireRow`

Comment: BTW, I tested on Excel 2016. There is a workaround to always asign a value to the leftmost cell right below header row (i.e. the leftmost cell on the first row of `DataBodyRange`). In this way, we *activate* the `DataBodyRange`. Then, your code works perfect after this.

Comment: @Nicholas Yes that's interesting to know. If the "only row" has data then ``.Delete` ing it is ok. These are anomalies... however I both methods should work. My code does not need to assign data to the only row, I prefer that explicit way, over assigning some bogus data temporarily.

Comment: Have you tried to select entires rows of `DataBodyRange`, and then delete them by right clicking and chosing `delete` in the menu, it would still raise an error even with condition `If .Rows.count > 1`.

Comment: Yep, you are right, there's a lot of edge cases here. I am testing a new version that handles all these case. @Nicholas

Comment: @Nicholas I have come to the conslucsion (which in fact I have had a while ago) that it's safer to work relative to the `HeaderRowRange`. I have changed like that, and it passed all the edge cases (except for an empty array of course).

Comment: I just found today after running your program, the table `foobar` only has one row now (not 15). Not sure if this is because Excel has updated its VBA syntax recently. This answer probably needs to be updated, too.

Comment: @Nicholas how did that happen? what are the circumstances?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus. I added `Sheet2.ListObjects("foobar").Resize Sheet2.ListObjects("foobar").HeaderRowRange.Resize(16)` at the end of your subroutine `Testing` and then things went back to normal; otherwise, the table only has one row of data, the rows below are not considered as in table `foobar`. It's strange because the code used to work well but just recently I found this problem.

Comment: @Nicholas is the number of columns in the array the same as in the table?